# How to get nth file segment of a file randomly?

Tags: java, file, stream, buffer

I have a file, and I want to divide it in chunks of `max_size = 1mb`.

Now for example if I have a file - **file.zip** of size **10 MB**, my file segments are file.zip.1, file.zip.2 . . . . file.zip.n

So given a **n**, can I directly retrieve **file.zip.n**?

Or in other words I dont want to loop through the entire file to get the **nth** file segment. Is there any way by which I can get the iterator to the position in which the nth segment starts?

Comment: show us what you have tried

Comment: I am still thinking about how to randomly pick a segment. Haven't tried yet

Comment: Show us the code you've tried

Comment: I still haven't tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it!

Had to create an object `RandomAccessFile` class, and use the `seek()` method to skip required number of bytes.